Pytest-BDD scenario outline with empty field
I am upgrading the code I am work on from Python 3.7 to Python 3.12 and also all the packages used to the last version.
I have a problem with pytest-bdd, where I moved from pytest==7.4.2 and pytest-bdd==4.1.0 to pytest==8.3.1 and pytest-bdd==7.2.0.
I have a scenario like this:
Scenario Outline:
    Given <tested> tested objects
    And <untested> untested objects
    When we use them
    Then we have <objects>

    Examples: All tested
    | tested   | untested | objects   |
    | A, B     |          | (A, B)    |
    | A, B, C  |          | (A, B, C) |


    Examples: All untested
    | tested | untested | objects |
    |        | A, B     | ()      |
    |        | A, B, C  | ()      |

    Examples: Both cases
    | tested | untested | objects |
    |  A, B  | C        | (A, B)  |


and the code is something like this (I modified the code changing from angular to curly brackets):
@given(parsers.parse("{tested} tested objects"))
def get_tested_object(context, tested):
    ...


@given(parsers.parse("{untested} untested objects"))
def get_untested_object(context, untested):
    ...


The last Examples: Both cases works fine, but I obtain for the first example the error:
pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: Given "untested objects"

and for the second:
pytest_bdd.exceptions.StepDefinitionNotFoundError: Step definition is not found: Given "tested objects"

So the problem is the empty field.
For the old pytest-bdd everything was fine, but I don't know how to modify the code for the new version.
Any suggestions?
